# Trying to find a fantasy Web comic about a vengeful witch that looks like a black wraith and yet cute

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

I cleared my browser history so I can't find it. I think it is still ongoing. It has a cutesy art style. One character is a vengeful wraith-like witch who pairs up with a girl on the girl's quest. The art style had noses. Other characters had mostly button noses.

Comment: Is it rated NSFW? If so then perhaps [this](https://www.oglaf.com/fuckbeasts/).

Comment: https://webcomiclibrary.tumblr.com/post/166121725314/witch-webcomic-masterpost/amp

Comment: Polymer City Chronicles?  http://www.polymercitychronicles.com/archive/20000118.html